# Extracting information from json input in python on the basis of other field's value

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "Steps": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "State": "PENDING",
                "StateChangeReason": {}
            },
            "ActionOnFailure": "CANCEL_AND_WAIT",
            "Name": "ABCD"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "State": "COMPLETED",
                "StateChangeReason": {}
            },
            "ActionOnFailure": "CANCEL_AND_WAIT",
            "Name": "KLMN"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Timeline": {
                    "CreationDateTime": 1469815629.4289999
                },
                "State": "PENDING",
                "StateChangeReason": {}
            },
            "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
            "Name": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to check whether the status of step with name = "KLMN" is completed or not. How can I do that in python.

> python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print
>   obj["Steps"]....'

how should I code print step to print COMPLETED

Comment: You already have code to load JSON into a Python object. All you have to do is iterate over that list and find what dictionary in that list matches your desired name. You already solved the JSON loading part; this is *just a Python list-with-dictionaries problem*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type this:

```
[step['Status']['State'] for step in data['Steps'] if step['Name']=='KLMN']
```

Where *data* is your data structure. You will get :

```
['COMPLETED']
```

Which is list with one element.

Comment: I am getting it as [u'COMPLETED']

Answer (score 1):

```
steps = {
    "Steps": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "State": "PENDING",
                "StateChangeReason": {}
            },
            "ActionOnFailure": "CANCEL_AND_WAIT",
            "Name": "ABCD"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "State": "COMPLETED",
                "StateChangeReason": {}
            },
            "ActionOnFailure": "CANCEL_AND_WAIT",
            "Name": "KLMN"
        },
        {
            "Status": {
                "Timeline": {
                    "CreationDateTime": 1469815629.4289999
                },
                "State": "PENDING",
                "StateChangeReason": {}
            },
            "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
            "Name": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}

if [step["Status"]["State"] for step in steps['Steps'] if step["Name"] == "KLMN"][0] == 'COMPLETED':
    #Do something
```